# netsh http add urlacl : add reservation for a group

Tags: http, windows-vista, netsh, wcf-configuration

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx) explain how to configure a namespace reservation for a user using `netsh.exe` as follows:

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

The parameter `user=` is said to be either user or user-group.
It works as described when I configure for a single user, but if I replace `DOMAN\user` with `DOMAIN\Administrators` or `DOMAIN\Users` I'm getting an error (1332).

**Q:** Why does it work for a user, but does not work for a group? Is syntax for a group different?

OS: Vista 32-bit

Note: The computer is not part of a domain, if that matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Administrators` is not part of `DOMAIN` but is part of `BUILTIN`, so correct command is:

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=BUILTIN\Administrators

Comment: Is it necessary to reserve for administrator accounts?

Comment: Just an extra note: groups in non-english version of Windows (can) have groupnames in the local language